# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' AWS SageMaker Studio Lab

Tags: numpy, amazon-sagemaker

I installed the numpy with Conda, pip and pip3, also tried installing from the requirements.txt file but I am still getting the following issue. Has anyone encountered this before and could please kindly suggest something?

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_732/1818554654.py in 
1 import os
----> 2 import numpy as np
3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
4 import pandas as pd
5 import random

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

numpy is built-in the default:Python environment in Studio Lab. If you open a new notebook with the File -> New -> Notebook, and choose the `default:Python` kernel, you should be able to import numpy without having to install the package.
[image: numpy-default-python-kernel]

If you would like to have a reproducible environment with a set of packages, see [this sample repo on creating custom environments](https://github.com/aws/studio-lab-examples/tree/main/custom-environments).

Comment: What if we need to select a different image (e.g., Tensorflow for CPU) and use numpy? I tried !pip install numpy, it says it is installed, but it still says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'" when I "import numpy"

Answer (score 0):

Numpy isn't preinstalled as a module you will need to install it yourself using pip or conda. Using notebooks just include a code block with the following:

```
!python -m pip install numpy
```

Suggestion to compile a list of required modules in a 'requirements.txt' file and install using:

```
!python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Just as an FYI, the base package list is as follows:

> Python 3.9 bzip2 build-essential curl git libgl1-mesa-glx nano rsync
> unzip wget ca-certificates pip ipykernel-6.4

Have a look at this link for more info.
[SageMaker - Manage your environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-lab-use-manage.html)